# Sphinx and TypedDict

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx, python-typing

I defined in my code a TypedDict like this:

```
class VectorDict(TypedDict):   
    x: float
    y: float
    z: float
```

and when I generate the documentation, I get the following result:

[image]

How can I suppress everything after `->` and/or modify it?

Comment: Do you use `automodule`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn: please have a look at my answer in order to help me giving a proper formulation. thanks!

Comment: @mauro include your `.rst` file and a picture of the `.html` output. In the question you didn't include a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) in the class, and that's the difference to the code you showed in the answer. Notice [the examples linked in this page](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a docstring:

```
class VectorDict(TypedDict):   
    """
    Description here
    """

    x: float
    y: float
    z: float
```

With this I obtain:

[image]